# Ionic 5 File INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR in android phones above android 9.0

Tags: android, angular, file, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing Ionic 5 app and I implemented download file feature in one page.
Problem is that when user tries to download file from phone (which os is above Android 9), user gets INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR.

Here's my code for downloading file.

```
 /**
   * Download file from url and save it to device
   * @param filename: Save file name
   * @param url: File url
   */
  public downloadFile(filename: string, url: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe(async result => {
        const downloadPath = await this.getDownloadPath();
        this.file.writeFile(downloadPath, filename, result, {replace: true}).then(fileEntry => {
          return resolve(fileEntry);
        }).catch(error => {
          return reject(error);
        });
      }, error => {
        return reject(error);
      });
    });
  }

  /**
   * Get download path
   */

  public async getDownloadPath() {
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      return this.file.documentsDirectory;
    }

    // To be able to save files on Android, we first need to ask the user for permission
    // We do not let the download proceed until they grant access
    await this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(
      result => {
        if (!result.hasPermission) {
          return this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
      });
    return this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/Download/';
  }
```

This code works fine in iPhones and android phones (which os is below 9.0)

Has anyone experienced this issue?
Any help would be apprecaited.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a known bug. ([Bug report on Github](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/408))

Try editing your *config.xml*:

```
    <platform name="android">
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
```

(line added is *android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"* to *application*)

Good luck!